# Android Cardviews and XML Loading Images Make App Lag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-cardview

I'm using 4 cardviews in XML, and they are only loading a picture and a textview each. Not using a RecyclerView or anything dynamic.
My Navigation drawer opens with so much lag and the entire app lags after adding the cardviews. Is there a better way to implement these cardviews?
These are simply nested within a Linearlayout.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.jesse.apbiologystudyappv2.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_1_natural_selection"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/apple_tree" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Natural Selection and Evolution"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_2_descent_and_ancestry"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/gravestones" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descent and Ancestry"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_3_speciation"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/dinosaur" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Speciation and Extinction"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_4_origin_of_life"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bacteria" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Origin of Life"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should probably try it using a RecyclerView, it manages the memory very well, and you will only need to create only 1 CardView element, also, be careful with image sizes.  Cheers

Comment: "Android Cardviews make entire app laggy" -- how precisely have you determined this? Use method tracing to determine exactly where you are spending your time. BTW, one way to help here is to get rid of the `RelativeLayouts`, as they are not needed. `CardView` inherits from `FrameLayout`, and you can center content in a `FrameLayout` using `layout_gravity`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm removing the relative layout and I will implement a recyclerview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use RecyclerView to manage memory as well. To do this you need only one CardView.

activity_main.xml :

```
 <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     tools:context="com.example.jesse.apbiologystudyappv2.MainActivity">

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lstActions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:padding="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

cardview_item.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view_1_natural_selection"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/imgActoun" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtActoun"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a class ActionItem.java like this:

```
public class ActionItem
{
private final int mTitleResID;
private final int mIconResID;

public ActionItem(int titleResID, int iconResID)
{
    this.mTitleResID = titleResID;
    this.mIconResID = iconResID;
}

public int getTitleResID()
{
    return mTitleResID;
}

public int getIconResID()
{
    return mIconResID;
}
}
```

onCreateView in MainActivity must be like this :

```
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    List<ActionItem> actionItems = new ArrayList<>();
    actionItems.add(new ActionItem(R.string.NaturalSelectionAndEvolution, R.drawable.apple_tree));
    actionItems.add(new ActionItem(R.string.DescentAndAncestry, R.drawable.gravestones));
    RecyclerView lstActions = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lstActions);
    ActionAdapter actionAdapter = new ActionAdapter(actionItems);
    lstActions.setAdapter(actionAdapter);

    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}
```

Add ActionAdapter Like this:

```
public class ActionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActionAdapter.ActionHolder>
{
private final List<ActionItem> mActionItems;

public ActionAdapter(List<ActionItem> actionItems)
{
    this.mActionItems = actionItems;
}

@Override
public ActionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new ActionHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ActionHolder actionHolder, int position)
{
    ActionItem actionItem = mActionItems.get(position);
    actionHolder.mTxtTitle.setText(actionItem.getTitleResID());
    actionHolder.mImgIcon.setImageResource(actionItem.getIconResID());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return this.mActionItems.size();
}

public class ActionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    protected final TextView mTxtTitle;
    protected final ImageView mImgIcon;

    public ActionHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        mImgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgAction);
        mTxtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAction);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful, I've never implemented recyclerview before

Comment: After the whole implementation, the only error I have is that `List<ActionItems> actions = new ArrayList<>(); is claimed to be` "unreacheable", so there could be something in ActionAdapter not being reached. Sorry I don't completely understand all of ActionAdapter, so can you help me with what's wrong here? Thanks

Comment: @JesseZhang Can I see full implemented of onCreateView method?

Comment: `public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
        List<ActionItem> actionItems = new ArrayList<>();
        actionItems.add(new ActionItem(R.string.NaturalSelectionAndEvolution, R.drawable.apple_tree));
        actionItems.add(new ActionItem(R.string.DescentAndAncestry, R.drawable.gravestones));
        RecyclerView lstActions = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.lstActions);
        ActionAdapter actionAdapter = new ActionAdapter(actionItems);
        lstActions.setAdapter(actionAdapter);
    }`

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, but the error occurs after writing `ActionAdapter actionAdapter = new ActionAdapter();` Once that line is written, the `List<ActionItem> actionItems = new ArrayList<>();` is unreachable, but before writing that line it lets me declare actionItems as a new list just fine.

Comment: I edit onCreateView  segment in my answer. 
Any code after return statement unreachable.

Comment: -______- can't believe i missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Fred's answer with a few changes. Instead of putting this

```
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    List<ActionItem> actionItems = new ArrayList<>();
    actionItems.add(new ActionItem(R.string.NaturalSelectionAndEvolution, R.drawable.apple_tree));
    actionItems.add(new ActionItem(R.string.DescentAndAncestry, R.drawable.gravestones));
    RecyclerView lstActions = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lstActions);
    ActionAdapter actionAdapter = new ActionAdapter(actionItems);
    lstActions.setAdapter(actionAdapter);

    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}
```

in onCreateView, I implemented it all in onCreate of MainActivity and put some declerations at the top of the class:

```
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private List<ActionItem> actionItems = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView listOfCards;
private ActionAdapter actionAdapter;
```

I was still getting a lot of lag, however, and it was due to XML loading the images. So, I used the Glide dependency available on Github instead. In ActionAdapter, I added a context requirement and then changed  onBindViewHolder. The context requirement is there to satisfy Glide's method which requires a context.

```
public class ActionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActionAdapter.ActionHolder> {
private final List<ActionItem> mActionItems;
private Context mContext;

public ActionAdapter(List<ActionItem> actionItems, Context context) {
    this.mActionItems = actionItems;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ActionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new ActionHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ActionHolder actionHolder, int position) {
    ActionItem actionItem = mActionItems.get(position);
    actionHolder.mTxtTitle.setText(actionItem.getTitleResID());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(actionItem.getIconResID()).into(actionHolder.mImgIcon);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.mActionItems.size();
}

public class ActionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected final TextView mTxtTitle;
    protected final ImageView mImgIcon;

    public ActionHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mImgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgAction);
        mTxtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

}

As you can see, i removed actionHolder.mImgIcon .setText.... from onBindViewHolder and replaced it with the Glide command. This makes the application skip no frames when launching and produce no more occurences of lag when opening the navigation drawer. Turns out the lag was produced by a combination of redundant RelativeLayouts, XML insertion of the picture (rather than the more efficient glide) and not using a RecyclerView.